# Keep track of which files are created by a certain process

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, maya

I'm using a Python (3.3) script to run a command that will render a whole bunch of image files for an animation film.

While it's rendering, it creates an empty image file every time it starts a new frame of the animation, and when it's done rendering that frame, it saves the image over that empty file and moves onto the next frame.

The python script starts this rendering process by running another script using:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
```

Is it at all possible to check which files were created during this process?

The reason being, someone may wish to stop the render before it finishes, but when they do so there will be an empty image file left over. I'd like to have the script delete the empty images when the big red *Stop Render* button is pushed, but I cannot simply delete all empty images because there may be other computers rendering - the empty images are there to prevent multiple computers rendering the same frame (they skip that frame if the image file for it exists).

If it helps, all the computers use Windows 7, and the animation program that does the rendering is Maya (2014).

If there's no easy way, I'd be happy to use any kind of ugly hack to get the job done :)

Comment: My god, you complicated yourself too much with that stuff, I don't have an answer for you, unfortunately, but I truly recommend you to look for an app, plugin, package, rendering instead of you the images. What you are trying to develop is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this in Maya, you can use mayapy interpeter that comes with Maya (rather than mayaBatch or maya -r). Inside of standalone you can run any script(s) you need to setup the render, execute it, and post-process the results. At a minimum, that will let you handle one frame at a time and use python to submit the images one at a time.

A basic setup would be:

1. Create a python script that does what you need to do and works correctly inside the maya python interpeter. The script will be run as if it were in the maya listener, so you can import `maya.cmds` and use maya features as needed.
2. If the script needs command line arguments, use sys.argv to retrieve them. When you run the script, any arguments you pass in will be available in sys.argv.
3. Your script can get access to all of Maya's functionality by importing `maya.standalone` and calling it's initialize method (more details [here](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/index.html?url=files/Python_Python_from_an_external_interpreter.htm,topicNumber=d30e727177))
4. From the command line, run the mayapy.exe that lives in the bin folder of your maya install.  The -s flag allows you to specify a script to run, so you'll pass in the python script as an argument, followed by any other arguments you need: something like `"path/to/mayapy.exe" -s "path/to/yourscript.py" arg1 arg2 arg3`.
5. You won't be able to catch a user cancelling via control-c but you could request cancellation from outside using a TCP connection to the maya command port, or even just by prompting for user input after each frame

For a fancier operation you can run an rpc server inside your Maya using something like [ZeroMQ](http://zeromq.org/) or [RpyC](http://rpyc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).  You could also make your own with a [WSGI server listening to the http port](https://github.com/theodox/standaloneRPC).

You can also look in to 3d party render management systems. There are some open-source ones [here](http://opensourcevfx.org/tag/render-queue/)

Comment: Really helpful info, thanks :) The only problem with rendering one frame at a time is that maya has to load the scene file for every frame, which takes several minutes.

Comment: Since your render script is inside of maya, you have the whole maya API to play with.  You can probably catch pre- or post-frame conditions with the [prepareRender command](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/CommandsPython/prepareRender.html)

Comment: The render script is outside of maya, it just calls the command-line render command for each shot with the appropriate frame range

Comment: I meant, if you use mayapy to host the process. See the edit above